# Angular-cli: compile a less file to a global css

Tags: angular, webpack, less, angular-cli

I've setup my app to use `less`. I can use `less` filess for my components just fine. However, **I need to compile one `less` file to a global `css` to be included in the root index.html**.

I read that the newest angular-cli version (I'm using `"angular-cli": "1.0.0-beta.19-3",`) uses webpack, but I cannot find documentation on how it's implemented, or a webpack file to add this instruction to.

How can I setup my angular-cli app to compile a less file to be used globally?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add your less file to the `apps[0].styles` in `angular-cli.json`. For instance

```
"apps": [
  {
    "styles": [
      "main.less"
    ]
  }
```

It will then automatically be included in your bundle. You can import/reference other less files from `main.less` as usual and you can add any number of entries to `apps[0].styles`.

This is also where you can add styles from vendors (such as packages in `node_modules`).

Paths in `angular-cli.json` are relative to the `src` directory.

Comment: I did this but unfortunately it's not working. I always assume I'm doing something wrong so I'm still looking though. Have you run into any hiccups? I created the file ``main.less`` in src and added it to angular-cli.json. I even installed less via npm. Is there something else I might be missing?